# How do I upgrade from OptaPlanner to Timefold?

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

[We forked OptaPlanner as Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/) some time ago. We often get this question:

Timefold changes all import statements and dependencies. How do I migrate an OptaPlanner codebase to Timefold efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to manually change imports statements, dependencies, etc. Just run a single command:

1. Pick the right Timefold version:

   - If you're on OptaPlanner 8, use Timefold 0.8.x.
   - If you're on OptaPlanner 9, use Timefold 1.x (currently 0.9.x).
2. Copy paste the Maven or Gradle command [from here](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/#upgrade-from-optaplanner-to-timefold). For Maven it looks like this:

   ```
   mvn org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.46.0:run -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=ai.timefold.solver:timefold-solver-migration:0.8.39 -Drewrite.activeRecipes=ai.timefold.solver.migration.ToLatest
   ```
3. Run the solver in your application. Verify **the score calculation speed is faster** now. Look at the last log message:

   ```
    INFO  Solving ended: ... score calculation speed (103322/sec) ...
   ```
4. Commit the local changes.

Comment: Report any issues with the migration [in Github issues](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Atimefold-solver-migration).

Comment: I get this error when I run that mvn command(with ./mvnw )  Error resolving version for plugin '.recipeArtifactCoordinates=ai.timefold.solver:timefold-solver-migration' from the repositories [local (C:\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository

Comment: Are you sure that this is the entire command? From the error message (which actually includes *property name* and not a plugin name, I am guessing at a typo on the command line.

Comment: No I'm not sure. I did a copy/paste of the posted cmd"mvn org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.45.3:run -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=ai.timefold.solver:timefold-solver-migration:0.8.38 -Drewrite.activeRecipes=ai.timefold.solver.migration.ToLatest" and ran it using ./mvnw instead of mvn in a windows terminal.

Comment: I've updated the answer to rewrite 4.46 and timefold 0.8.39, can you try again? I 'd love to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: What does `mvnw --version` print?